# Different method for the same question = different post?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In the post [Finding all solutions to $y^3 = x^2 + x + 1$ with $x,y$ integers larger than $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178499/finding-all-solutions-to-y3-x2-x-1-with-x-y-integers-larger-than-1), the OP presents a certain method of solution, and asks for advice.

While perusing it, I had a brainstorm for a very different method of attack. But I'm stuck half-way through my own solution, and want to get some help. Should I start a new, linked post (to acknowledge the different method being used), or post an answer or comment in the existing thread (to acknowledge that I'm trying to solve the same equation)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From your brief description, it sounds like you do indeed have your own independent question. It may be worthwhile linking to the other topic as a reference. Be careful to frame your question as "I want to understand how to make an argument like this work" rather than "Tell me how to find solutions to this equation".